# Are Active directory DNS records being public a security concern

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, security

For particular reasons, facing situation where all Active Directory DNS records like

_ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.foo.com

will be public, i.e not hosted only on internal DNS.

Naturally, relying on the secrecy of these things is never a strategy. All normal firewalls would be in place to prevent actual access to the internal servers.

My question is how big a deal is it that this is in a public DNS zone, from a security perspective? How much would it really help an attacker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is information that would be likely easily attainable if an attacker already had access to your internal network, it could allow a sophisticated actor to more finely craft an exploit specific to your environment from outside of your environment.  Though admittedly, the attacker would in most cases still need to gain access to the internal network to gain access.

Another angle; however unlikely, would be that using this information, a sophisticated attacker could design a rogue network to hijack your remote users by configuring servers/services on their network to intercept communications destined for DCs, or (if UNC Hardening is not configured on your clients) provide an alternate NETLOGON / SYSVOL share to apply undesirable group policies.  Admittedly far fetched.

---

That aside, I find it very unlikely that there would be such a situation where these records would actually *need* to be published publicly.  Usually in these cases, I find it more productive to move back a step in the decision making process to determine what earlier decision yielded such an undesirable configuration -- that is, reevaluate the answer to the question that led to this scenario and see if there is a more informed, creative, or technically sound decision that can be made.